# fixed points on $T^*Gr(2,4)$ under a certain action

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

The elements of $T^*Gr(2,4)$ can be viewed as pairs $\{(i,j)\ |\ j: \mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^4,\ i: \mathbb C^4 \to \mathbb C^2, i|_{j(\mathbb C^2)}=0\}$. If I decompose $\mathbb C^4 = \mathbb C \oplus \mathbb C^3$, then we can define an action of $\lambda(t): \mathbb C^*\to GL(4,\mathbb C)$ by sending $(i,j) \mapsto (ig, g^{-1}j)$, where $g = diag(1,t^{-1},t^{-1},t^{-1})$. How can I determine the fixed locus of this action? For reference I am trying to understand this application of Nakajima's lemma:

> **Lemma 3.2**: *The fixed point set of $\lambda(\mathbb C^*)$ in $\mathfrak M(v, w)$ is isomorphic to $\sqcup_{v^1 + v^2 = v}\mathfrak M(v^1,w^1) \times \mathfrak M(v^2,w^2)$.*

So it is supposed to decompose into cotangent bundles of smaller flag varieties, but I can't see how it works.